# Kendo UI TreeView cancel drop event with custom confirmation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, treeview, modal-dialog, confirm

Requirement:  Get confirmation from user using custom bootstrap modal prior to moving a treeview node by dragging and dropping.

I've looked everywhere and all the suggestions are to use JavaScript confirm dialog to cancel the drop event.  But, we don't want to use that as it's not as pretty as our custom dialogs.

Is there a suggested way to handle this?  Presumably the modal is asynchronous and the event is fired asynchronously also and completes the event before waiting for confirmation.

Ideally looking for something like this:

```
function onDrop(e) {
customModal.ConfirmationModal.open("Move Node", "Are you sure you want to move this?")
                        .then(function() {
                                // persist in db 
                            },
                            function() { // cancel drop

                                e.preventDefault();
                                customModal.ConfirmationModal.close(); 
                            })
                        .finally(function() {

                        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up just preventing default and manually moving the nodes myself.  If anyone has a cooler answer, feel free to let me know.  Solution below:

```
function onDrop(e)
        {
            if (e.valid)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var treeview = $("#yourtreeview").data("kendoTreeView");

                customModal.ConfirmationModal.open("Move Node", "Are you sure you want to move this?")
                        .then(function() {

                            var node = e.sourceNode; 

                            if (e.dropPosition == "over") 
                                treeview.append(e.sourceNode, $(e.destinationNode)); 
                            else
                            {
                                if (e.dropPosition == "before")  
                                    treeview.insertBefore(e.sourceNode, $(e.destinationNode));
                                else if (e.dropPosition == "after")  
                                    treeview.insertAfter(e.sourceNode, $(e.destinationNode));
                            } 
                        },
                            function() { // cancelled delete
                                // error

                            })
                        .finally(function() {
                            customModal.ConfirmationModal.close();
                        });

            } // e.valid 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the implementation of your modal, but shouldn't you be checking its return value? Are you sure your modal returns a promise? It should return a promise for `then()` to work as you intend.

As it's coded here, the modal always succeeds. It doesn't matter if they click OK or Cancel,  the first function in your `then()` clause is always run. Clicking Cancel isn't going to cause the "fail" function to execute. Try adding a parameter to the first function, say `function(result) {}` in your `then()` clause and see what value `result` contains. If it contains the value of what the user selected, then you can branch off of that.

```
customModal.open("Move Node", "Are you sure?").done(function (result) {
  if (result === "Ok") {
    // do work
  } else {
    // cancel
  }
});
```